# Unloading LaunchAgent from synchronized task (launchdaemon)

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sudo, launchd

I've got running daemon service in macOS.
Upon external event, it runs a script from another launchDaemon plist using `launchctl load`

Here the plist for this service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.uninstall</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/myprod/uninstall.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In the script itself I wish to unload all instances per user of a launchAgent service (this service has process per user). The unload command looks like this :

```
#!/bin/sh

for current_user in `/usr/bin/users`; 
do    
sudo -u $current_user /bin/launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myprod.agent.plist
done
```

This commands doesn't succeed however and the service remains.
but doing so manually from the shell command line, works just fine.

In an attempt to debug the issue, i've checked the logs and traced the working and the non-working command spawning :

work:

```
sudo:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=myself ; COMMAND=/bin/launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myprod.agent.plist
```

no-work:

```
sudo:     root : TTY=ttys004 ; PWD=/Users/myself/Desktop ; USER=myself ; COMMAND=/bin/launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myprod.agent.plist
```

I assume the command should succeed, since the script in both cases runs as root. the only difference is in the context and the value of `tty` which I don't understand what it is.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-F` option with `launchctl`:

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchAgents/...
```

> **-F**       Force the loading or unloading of the plist. *Ignore the
>                          Disabled key.*

If you don't use `-F` then you'll probably first need to disable the loaded daemon, then unload it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. Unfortunately adding the `-f` option didn't resolve the issue. I keep getting error code 1, and I'm not sure it comes from the `sudo` or from the `launchctl` part. notice that when I see the command printout in console , it says `TTY=unknown` .. I checked it but I guess it should bother since I switch from root to regular user and no password is being requested.

Comment: You really shouldn't need sudo in the command since the script should already be running as root. The location of where you run the daemon matters also. You might want to switch the location to "LaunchDaemons" instead of "LaunchAgents" (see this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/290946/10139). TTY is the shell session the task is running in; that really shouldn't be a factor.